# Session disappears on return to home page

Tags: asp.net

I have a web site running on Azure where a user can login then navigate to other pages (naturally). My problem is that when I return to the Index/Homepage the session just disappears. I thought it my have something to do with the login control and its authentication method in the code behind but I tried putting another login on another page with the same authenticate event but that is completely fine.

I haven't found anyone with a similar problem.

here is the code behind for index.aspx

```
string Connection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["****"].ConnectionString;
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {}
protected void Login1_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e) {
  string Username = Login1.UserName;
  string pwd = Login1.Password;
  SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(Connection);
  connection.Open();
  //SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT([*****], [*****]) FROM ***** WHERE [****] = '***' AND [****] = '****'", connection);
  string sqlUserName = "SELECT [****] ,[****] FROM ***** WHERE [*****] ='" + * * * * * +"' AND [*****] ='" + * * * +"'";
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlUserName, connection);
  string CurrentName;
  CurrentName = (string) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
  if(CurrentName != null) {
    Login1.FailureText = "Welcome";
    Session["User"] = Username;
    Session["LoggedIn"] = true;
    Label1.Text = Session["User"].ToString();
    if((bool) Session["LoggedIn"] == true && Session["User"].ToString() == "admin1") {
      HyperLink3.Visible = true;
    } else if((bool) Session["LoggedIn"] == true) {
      HyperLink1.Visible = true;
    }
  } else {
    Session["User"] = "";
  }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `if` statement must be bugging out somewhere, or CurrentName is null.

```
if (CurrentName != null)
        {
            Login1.FailureText = "Welcome";
            Session["User"] = Username;
            Session["LoggedIn"] = true ;
            Label1.Text = Session["User"].ToString();
            if ((bool)Session["LoggedIn"] == true && Session["User"].ToString() == "admin1")
            {
                HyperLink3.Visible = true;
            }
            else if ((bool)Session["LoggedIn"] == true)
            {
                HyperLink1.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        else
        {
            Session["User"] = "";

        }
```

The most likely culprit is the preceding SQL query. Double check your syntax with the SQL query. I'm not sure what the asterisk variables are you have combined in there, but they could be causing an issue. You should proceed with line-by-line debugging of that script. Catch it mid-way through and check the value of CurrentName.

Comment: The code sets up the session 'User' variable as I use it in SQL queries on other pages, but also when navigating back to the page I know it isn't running the login1_validate event again randomly unless i try and login as iv checked it.

I put the exact same code and login control on another page with no problems.

I just cant work out why the homepage does it. Thank you for the quick reply